# SSRS: Conditional Dataset Filter (Report Builder 3.0)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have several (multi select) parameters for my report which queries a huge table.  Rather than using the default 'Select All' with every parameter checkbox checked, I've UNIONed an "ALL" option to my parameter list and set that to the default, so my parameter options look like:

```
[ ] (Select All)
[X] ALL
[ ] Alabama
[ ] Alaska
[ ] Arizonia
[ ] Arkansas
etc...
```

I did this for performance purposes so that if "ALL" is selected, the query does not include it as another WHERE IN clause.  I acheive this using dynamic sql, which is a little bit of a pain.

*** So finally my question is, under "Filters" in the Dataset Properties, the traditional way to filter a dataset based on parameter selection is to for example set one to:

```
Expression: [US_STATE]
Operator: IN
Value: @parameter_STATE
```

Is there any way I can use this built in Dataset Filter (in Report Builder 3.0) to acheive:

```
IF @parameter_STATE = 'ALL' then 

    do nothing / don't include filter

ELSE

    Expression: [US_STATE]
    Operator: IN
    Value: @parameter_STATE
```

I assume there is a way to do this, which will be much easier than handling it with dynamic SQL?  Any information is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You could just use `WHERE @parameter_STATE = 'ALL' OR somecolumn IN (@parameter_STATE)`, no need for dynamic SQL

Comment: Thanks for the response, this may be very helpful.  How is this performance wise?  With the dynamic sql I was using joins on my params (ie @sql=N'select * from table a ' + case when @param_state = 'ALL' THEN N'' ELSE N'JOIN #param_vals b on a.state = b.state'END - doing that for several params